# Jetty ServletContainerInitialization (SCI ) doesn't call an Initializer provided inside a web-fragment

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, servlet-3.0

Here is the scenario,

- webapp contains a `web.xml`
- one of the jars contain ServletContainerInitializer

  `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainterInitializer`

We are pro grammatically starting jetty, by using XMLConfiguration which is configured with a server object.

```java
    XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(in);

    if (type.isInstance(server))
    {
        configuration.configure(server);

        return;
    }

    boolean success = false;

    for (Handler handler : ((Server) server).getHandlers())
    {
        if (type.isInstance(handler))
        {
            configuration.configure(handler);

            success = true;
        }
    }
```

here is the XML file that is used.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" id="Server">
<Set name="ThreadPool">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads">2</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">10</Set>
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
    </New>
</Set>
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="port">8080</Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
<Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
        <Arg type="String">src/main/webapp</Arg>
        <Arg type="String">/</Arg>
        <Set name="extraClasspath">S:/git/projects/p1/target/classes;           
        S:/maven.repo/org/apache/ahc/1.1.2/ahc-1.1.2.jar;
        S:/maven.repo/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.2.3.20110115/jaxb-xjc-2.2.3.20110115.jar;
        S:/maven.repo/com/springsource/org/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar;
        S:/maven.repo/com/springsource/org/jdom/1.0.0/jdom-1.0.0.jar;
        S:/maven.repo/org/apache/mina/1.1.9/mina-1.1.9.jar;
        S:/maven.repo/com/springsource/com/mysql/jdbc/5.1.6/jdbc-5.1.6.jar;
        </Set>
    </New>
</Set>
<Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
<Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
<Set name="sendDateHeader">true</Set>
<Set name="gracefulShutdown">1000</Set>
<Set name="dumpAfterStart">false</Set>
<Set name="dumpBeforeStop">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

When invoked from CLI, jetty DeploymentManager scans the classpath and calls the ServletContainerInitializer provided inside the jar files. What is the equivalent for that to be provided in the XML config file?

When the code is deployed as a war into a jetty installation everything works as expected.
So, that confirms everything is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Nambi,

Here's a link to the jetty documentation page that discusses using annotations in embedded mode: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/using-annotations-embedded.html

You just need to do the equivalent of the java code in xml - which is always in jetty very straightforward. If you need hints, then have a look at your distro and see what the etc/jetty-annotations.xml file is doing.

Also, if you have annotations inside of jars that are on the extraClasspath, then you need to be using 9.0.6-SNAPSHOT of jetty as I've only just implemented that feature :)

Jan

Comment: the only difference is XML vs Java. Ultimately both set "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext" as handler. My question is why "WebAppContent" doesn't trigger SCI ( ServletContainerInitializer ) during startup?  What additional handlers/beans that need to be configured, so that jetty can trigger SCI during container startup?